# Projective scheme over the integers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a projective scheme over $Spec(\mathbb{Z})$. Let $X_{p}$ be the reduction at $p$ of $X$. If for any prime $p$, $X_{p}$ is normal, can we deduce $X$ is normal? Or any counterexamples?

Comment: Do you mean "if for every $p$, $X_p$ is normal" or "If for at least one $p$, $X_p$ is normal"?

Comment: @Will Sawin  I means for every p. Maybe I need add a condition such that $X$ is flat over $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: What is the ring where the prime ideal $p$ "lives"?

Comment: Yes, flatness is needed, or else you can take the union of $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb F_p}$ and $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z$, glued at an $\mathbb F_p$-point of $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb F_p}$, whose mod $p$ fiber is $\mathbb P^1$, normal, and whose mod $q$ fiber is a point for any other point $q$, but is not normal.